# Caching PDO Prepared Statements in a class wrapper

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am in the process of updating old (messy) code from mysql_query() to PDO.

I understand that using prepared statements is good for both security and performance, however for the performance aspect to come into play, the prepare must be done first and then multiple executes afterwards. This would mean major rewrites in my code which are probably not worthwhile for the performance gain, but then I wondered if I could do it another way.

My proposed solution is to wrap the PDO class as follows :

```
 class PDOCached extends PDO {

      private $PreparedStatementCache;

      public function prepare($query) {

          if (!isset($this->PreparedStatementCache[$query])) {              
                $this->PreparedStatementCache[$query]=parent::prepare($query);
          }

          return $this->PreparedStatementCache[$query];
      }
 }
```

It works (i.e. I get the same results back), but I am not clear as to whether it allows me to take advantage of the performance gains. Any feedback/comments appreciated.

Note: I know this does not take into account $driver_options, but for this exercise that is not important.

---

UPDATE:

I have modified the class to make the caching optional:

```
 class PDOCached extends PDO {

      private $PreparedStatementCache;

      // WARNING: Does not take into account $driver_options
      public function prepare($query, $cached=false) {

          if (!$cached) return parent::prepare($query);

          if (!isset($this->PreparedStatementCache[$query])) {  
                // WARNING: Assumes try/catch error handling            
                $this->PreparedStatementCache[$query]=parent::prepare($query);
          }

          return $this->PreparedStatementCache[$query];
      }
 }
```

Comment: typical web application very seldom runs similar queries within processing single request. Are you sure you have such a case? Don't you think of rewriting them, if so, to one query using JOIN or IN?

Comment: I have some places where there is a loop that calls one of a few different functions depending on context. Within those functions, data for the specific record is retrieved and formatted for presentation. To rewrite the code or move the prepare statements outside of the loop would be a big deal, so I am looking at alternatives like this.

Comment: It might be wroth doing an actual benchmark

Answer (score 2):

From a technical performance standpoint you are correct.  You will gain from caching the PDOStatement (has to be used in the same connection).  However, how often within the same Mysql connection and PHP request are running a query, moving on and executing another query, then going back to the first query?  This would seem to get confusing and open the potential of mistakenly changing a bound variable (if you use bindParam()).

I think the performance gain you'll find from this is only micro optimization and you'll just be adding complexity--not a good thing since it's already complex enough you'd need to spend time trying to clean up your loop queries to not have the overlapping nested query need.

BTW: security alone is more than enough of a good reason to move to prepared statements and invest the conversion time.

Comment: I'm not caching the query string, I'm caching the statement object returned by PDO::prepare. The query string is just the key in the array that caches the statement object.

Comment: @BenHolness got it.  If you have hold of the PDOStatement object on the the same connection, it should technically be 'faster' as you the db doesn't have calculate how it will execute again. See my update

Comment: Cool. So I have now added a 'cached' parameter to the prepare function in PDOCached, so I only use that when I know a statement will be used multiple times in one page load, then I should get the performance benefit as well as the security benefit (although everything was already escaped in the original code, so I don't know how much extra this really adds). I have updated the original post with the new code.

Answer (score -1):

I used the cached prepared statement pattern in a persistency layer PDO wrapper class that contains as one of its members an array of variables that are 'permanently' bind to query results. This way I was able use this as an Iterator.